# Could one actually build electronics without EE degree?

Tags: hobbyist

I understand that a teach yourself electronics book can "teach you electronics", but just how far can that take you developmentally?

I want to have the ability to solve a problem requiring the development of a specific electric motor for example, of certain HP rating and speed as well as knowing the calculations and thicknesses required. I have spent a long time teaching myself the branches of math, and have come to enjoy it too, but I do not want to spend years learning all of the math when only some of it is required.

Can I "thoroughly" build electronics with a teach yourself book? My predicament is that I support a household with a full time manufacturing job that pays well, but gives me no room for full time at a university. I understand that online classes can only go so far as well. My apologies if the above makes no sense in any way.

Comment: Have at it. I'm 100% self-educated, for the worse or better of it. I see no reason you can't achieve what you want. Whenever I wanted to do something bad enough, I've been able to complete it. I'd say the answer to your question is "yes."

Comment: Another hobbyist here. A bit hard to get more technical permanent positions but plenty of freelances. In my experience, if I research about the topic at hand I can know my limitations pretty well and consult a qualified person if necessary. Also I've been shocked how many times I've interacted with "official" EEs with degrees that lack in knowledge and experience.. And have also worked with great EEs which have taught me a lot..

Comment: Degree is a paper certifying you have learnt something. You can learn the same uncertified.

Comment: Yes you can .When I was a child in the 1960s most people in Dunedin where I was born that built electronic items did not have any formal EE qualifications .Nowdays degrees for better or worse are much more common.Sure a degree is useful in a regulated labor market but if you think your manufacturing job is OK then skip the degree and start building .

Comment: It sounds like your real question is about a college or college-equivalent EE education, not about a degree. There is absolutely nothing about having a degree that makes it any easier or harder to do what you want. At best, a degree helps you to convince others that you have such abilities, but even for that, they are less useful than they once were. Even at their best, though, they do nothing to help you have the abilities, only to help you communicate to other humans that you have them.

Comment: If you really do mean the degree, then yea, Passerby has you covered. If, as I suspect, you really are concerned with the ability to design a thing and have a device made to your design work as you intended it to, then you might want to change the question to reflect that.

Comment: @EugeneSh., not quite correct. Degree is a paper certifying that you learned with passing grades a set of introductory disciplines that are necessary to design good electronics, not just "something" (although in American system of education the concept of freedom and self-selection of curriculum by students defy this idea of consistency in education).

Comment: Yes, you definitely can. If you can get ongoing time with any experienced electronics engineers, discussion with them as you're learning can be very useful. If you can get ongoing time with any decent experienced electronics engineers, it can be invaluable. Enjoy learning, explore and look into things to understand them. The very best of luck with your future.

Comment: I heard that the writer of the famous book Art of Electronics never took a EE class in his life. He is a physicist. Check here what he says at 3:06 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCI3B5eT9NA&feature=youtu.be&t=186 But he is a smart man. He also had many smart scientists and engineers around him that you probably will never have.

Comment: @user1234, it is quite obvious that fundamental Physics supersedes EE, which is just a specific application, narrowed down to a set of specific problems. So there is no surprise at all. I myself used to be a physicist. But wide systematic background always allow to tackle particular problems and understand particular approaches and engineering solutions faster than having no background at all. That's why I advise for systematic education under supervision of teaching professionals.

Comment: If you want an example of real-world electronics, with various interferers, go to https://www.robustcircuitdesign.com/downyloads/ and scroll to bottom of the downloads. That last article is about Managing the Interferers in a Thermistor (the sensor) Signal Chain. The article discusses many realworld problems in electronics, including how capacitive loads usually make opamps produce non-flat frequency response (plots are shown) or simply become irksome oscillators.

Comment: @AliChen I agree, even for an EE who has studied telecommunications in bachelors and later on if he develops interest to power or power electronics it will be very hard to learn himself and be able to get a job/career in that specific region. Even inside the EE field there are many specializations now requires so much experience and knowledge. I think the answer to this question is yes for a layman but ONLY if he is determined crazy to self study in an autistic level or lucky enough to be given opportunity. Otherwise it will remain as a hobby.

Comment: I make good money designing gear for the TV broadcast industry with no degree, so it can be done, but I spend several thousand a year on journals and about the same on continuing ed courses, more then someone with the paper you got to stay on top of your game.

Comment: @DanMills How did you get hired for your first job as designer or EE without any degree and job experience? What made them do you think to hire you by looking at your CV? You must have had a very strong network/reference to be chosen among hundreds of hungry applicants these days.

Comment: @user1234 I turned up at a hiring fair with a rather good 2U rack mount all digital AM transmitter of my own design, and a HAM license, plenty of companies would not go for it, but one did (That prototype became a product!). I had been into electronics and small core programming since <small child>. Apparently an 18 year old who could design electronics and layout RF PCBs, write DSP and VHDL and work a drill press and press brake well enough to put the hardware together had value. Fact is, for RF folk there are not hundreds of hungry applicants, far too many see it as a black art.

Comment: @DanMills If you are that smart what really prevented you to get a degree? Very interesting.

Comment: @user1234 Meh, someone offered me lighting design gig on a rock circus tour that looked a lot more fun then uni (I got to fix 500kVA rotating machines with duct tape). I was never that good at putting up with the academentia ("To three significant figures calculate the value of the series resistor for the power on Led", My response : "Well it is a 12.0V rail so anything between about 600 ohms and 10.0k should be fine, pick something you use elsewhere on the BOM", is correct, pragmatic and wrong in every possible way in a university context). I could not tolerate 3 years of the bullshit.

Answer (score 5):

> Could one actually build electronics without EE degree?

Yes. There is no legal or other barrier. Millions of people do it every day. Even children.

Answer (score 4):

> I understand that a teach yourself electronics book can "teach you electronics", but just how far can that take you developmentally?

There're two prerequisites:

1. You must really want and need to learn the things, and then have a need to get result of this learning (in some activity or product);
2. You **must** start with basics. When you understand the basics, you will be able to understand the higher level knowledge, its implications, limitations and correlation to other knowledge.

> I want to have the ability to solve a problem requiring the development of a specific electric motor for example, of certain HP rating and speed as well as knowing the calculations and thicknesses required.

In this example, you not only need to know electronics engineering, you also need to know basics of physics in general, you must have some idea about materials science.

> I have spent a long time teaching myself the branches of math

So you should already have a good foundation.

> I do not want to spend years learning all of the math when only some of it is required.

If you **really** know what you want to achieve (e.g. make a motor like in your example), then you will be able to find related theoretical knowledge, examples and implementations for it. In addition, you will be able to ask informed questions here and there, and be able to evaluate the responses. Reverse engineering (looking how others do it) can also be very helpful.

> Can I "thoroughly" build electronics with a teach yourself book?

What we can definitely state that you will be able to do what is written in the book. Many books assume that you have some understanding and knowledge prior you start with them.

And finally,

> Could one actually build electronics without EE degree?

Yes, depending on the quality of instructions given (in the book, in the manual, in the guide), tools you have (good tools are usually 40% of the success), your interest in subject (another 40% of success) and wish to get the end product of your activities.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, one can build "electronics" without EE degree. The question is "what kind of electronics" it would be? If you need your "electronics" to fly, withstand electrical, mechanical, thermal and radiation hazard, keep running for years or decades while keeping accuracy, you better get a good EE degree. College education provides you with systematic background in many adjacent disciplines, and in "electronics" you might need them together. Without good systematic education you might have many blanks, so your design will be deficient, and will be rejected/fail in marketplace.